Queuing theory - Probability of servers being busy when packets are discarded if all servers are busy
Here are some simple twists on a queuing question that I cannot seem to get my head around.
a) Suppose that a server $S$ receives packets at rate $\lambda$. Call this arrival process $A$. The time that $S$ takes to process a single packet is exponentially distributed with parameter $\mu$, and any packets received while $S$ is busy are discarded. What is the probability that $S$ is busy at time $t>0$?
My approach is to define a Poisson process $L$ of rate $\mu$ independent from $A$ and note that the probability that $S$ is busy at a time $t>0$ is precisely the probability that either there has been at least one arrival at time $t$, and the last arrival seen is from $A$ (and not from $L$). These are two independent events, so
\begin{equation*}
\mathbb{P}(\text{busy at time }t) = (1-e^{-(\lambda+\mu) t})\frac{\lambda}{\lambda+\mu}.
\end{equation*}
I must be mistaken however as some quick simulations with $\lambda = 2$ and $\mu =1$ seem to give me a constant answer for all $t$ of around $0.573$...
Edit: My simulations were incorrect, I now get about $0.64$ for $t=1$, which is very close to the value predicted by the formula above. Other values of $t$ seem to be predicted accurately as well.
b) Suppose the same setup, but that we now have servers $S_1,\dotsc, S_k$ and want to compute the probability that all $S_i$s are busy at time $t$ (if all servers are busy and a packet arrives, it is again discarded).
Any help is appreciated.

The problem is not completely formulated. Is the raw arrival process Poisson of rate $\lambda$, and independent of service times?

@Michael Yes, the arrival process is Poisson of rate $\lambda$, independent of service times and service times are i.i.d. exponentially distributed with parameter $\mu$.

Then the steady state fraction of time being busy is $\frac{\lambda}{\lambda+\mu}$. The probability of being busy at any particular time $t\geq 0$ depends on whether or not the server starts out empty. Assuming $P[\mbox{busy at $0$}]=0$, I still get a different answer from yours. I think your derivation is incorrect. I would solve this using an ODE.

Do you have a nice proof of this? Or is it essentially the argument above?
I must have gone wrong somewhere in my simulations. For this example I was assuming that the server starts empty. How does the answer change if it starts full?

I would define $f(t)=P[\mbox{busy at $t$}]$, with initial condition $f(0)=0$, then $$f(t+\delta) \approx f(t)(1-\mu\delta) + (1-f(t))\lambda\delta$$ which is accurate for small $\delta>0$ and gives an ODE as $\delta \searrow 0$. For just a derivation of the time average fraction of time being busy of $\lambda/(\lambda + \mu)$, you can use an easier renewal theory argument, or just define the 2-state CTMC.

I am not familiar neither with renewal theory nor with 2-state CTMCs. Could you please explain or point me to relevant resources?

You don't know how to analyze an M/M/1 queue with a continuous time Markov chain (CTMC)? This is problem 1 for queueing theory. You are dealing with (a) an M/M/1/1 queue; (b) an M/M/k/k queue.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

Assume service times are i.i.d. exponential $\mu$, and the raw arrivals are Poisson $\lambda$ and independent of service times. Then part (a) is a M/M/1/1 queue (which can be modeled by a 2 state CTMC); part (b) is a M/M/k/k queue (and can be modeled by a $k+1$ state CTMC).
Getting an answer for probabilities at a particular time $t$ is typically much harder than getting answers as $t\rightarrow\infty$. However, for part (a) you can do it by defining $Q(t) \in \{0,1\}$ as the number of jobs in the system at time $t$ and
$$ f(t) = P[Q(t)=1] \quad \forall t \geq 0$$
with initial condition $f(0)=0$ (if we start empty) or $f(0)=1$ (if we start busy). Then we can derive an ODE by fixing $t$ and observing for small $\delta>0$
\begin{align}
f(t+\delta) &= P[Q(t+\delta)=1]\\
&=P[Q(t+\delta)=1|Q(t)=1]f(t) + P[Q(t+\delta)=1|Q(t)=0](1-f(t))\\
&\approx e^{-\mu\delta}f(t) + (1-e^{-\lambda \delta})(1-f(t))\\
&\approx (1-\mu\delta)f(t) + \lambda\delta (1-f(t)) 
\end{align}
which assumes that $\delta$ is so small that we get either no transition or one transition during the interval $[t, t+\delta]$.
This is accurate for small $\delta>0$ and as $\delta \searrow 0$ we get the ODE
$$ f'(t) = \lambda - (\lambda+\mu)f(t)$$
For initial condition $f(0)=0$ this has solution
$$ f(t) = \left(\frac{\lambda}{\lambda + \mu}\right)\left(1 - e^{-(\lambda + \mu)t}\right) \quad \forall t \geq 0$$
which yields
$$\lim_{t\rightarrow\infty} f(t) = \frac{\lambda}{\lambda+\mu}$$
which is consistent with the steady state solution of the 2 state CTMC.
